# How to reset object "data"?

Tags: vbscript

For example, in string variables `H` and `G` I have html content:

```
Set oHtmlFile = CreateObject("HtmlFile")
oHtmlFile.write H

<do some parsing on oHtmlFile object>

oHtmlFile.write G
...
```

If I do above now `oHTMLFile` contains both `H` and `G` content.

How can I reset `oHtmlFile` object before writing `G` data, without creating new object (`CreateObject("HtmlFile")`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further details about your real world problem, it's difficult to come up with good/practical advice. In theory you can manipulate the oHtmlFile's document tree by using properties like .inner/outerHTLM and .innerTEXT or calling functions like .create*, .remove*, or .append*.

In code:

```
  Dim oDOM  : Set oDOM = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
  Dim sHTML : sHTML    = "<html><head></head><body></body></html>"
  WScript.Echo "Empty", TypeName(oDOM), "oDOM"
  dumpDoc oDOM

  oDOM.write sHTML
  WScript.Echo "After .write", qq(sHTML)
  dumpDoc oDOM

  sHTML = "<p>G</p><p>H</p>"
  oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).innerHTML = sHTML
  WScript.Echo "After setting body's .innerHTML to", qq(sHTML)
  dumpDoc oDOM

  sHTML = "pipapo"
  oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).childNodes(1).innerTEXT = sHTML
  WScript.Echo "After changing second P's .innerTEXT to", qq(sHTML)
  dumpDoc oDOM

  oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).removeChild oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).childNodes(0)
  WScript.Echo "After deleting first P"
  dumpDoc oDOM

  Dim oNode : Set oNode = oDOM.createElement("h1")
  oNode.appendChild oDOM.createTextNode("tritratrulala")
  oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).appendChild oNode
  WScript.Echo "After using DOM to append an H1"
  dumpDoc oDOM

  sHTML = "<span>abracadabra</span>"
  oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).childNodes(0).outerHTML = sHTML
  WScript.Echo "After overwriting first P's outerHTML", qq(sHTML)
  dumpDoc oDOM

Sub dumpDoc(oDOM)
  If oDOM.documentElement Is Nothing Then
     WScript.Echo "", "oDOM.documentElement Is Nothing"
     WScript.Echo "", "oDOM.childNodes.length", oDOM.childNodes.length
  Else
     WScript.Echo "", "oDOM.documentElement:",  oDOM.documentElement.tagName
     WScript.Echo "", "oDOM.childNodes.length", oDOM.childNodes.length
     dumpTree oDOM.documentElement, 2
  End If
  WScript.Echo "-----------------"
End Sub

Sub dumpTree(oNode, nL)
  Select Case oNode.nodeType
    Case 1
      WScript.Echo Space(nL), oNode.nodeType, oNode.tagName, qq(Replace(oNode.innerHTML, vbCrLf, ""))
      Dim oChild
      For Each oChild In oNode.childNodes
          dumpTree oChild, nL + 1
      Next
    Case 3
      WScript.Echo Space(nL), oNode.nodeType, oNode.nodeName, qq(Replace(oNode.nodeValue, vbCrLf, ""))
  End Select
End Sub
```

output:

```
demoHtmlFile - demo HtmlFile
===============================================================================
Empty HTMLDocument oDOM
 oDOM.documentElement Is Nothing
 oDOM.childNodes.length 0
-----------------
After .write "<html><head></head><body></body></html>"
 oDOM.documentElement: HTML
 oDOM.childNodes.length 1
   1 HTML "<HEAD></HEAD><BODY></BODY>"
    1 HEAD ""
     1 TITLE ""
    1 BODY ""
-----------------
After setting body's .innerHTML to "<p>G</p><p>H</p>"
 oDOM.documentElement: HTML
 oDOM.childNodes.length 1
   1 HTML "<HEAD></HEAD><BODY><P>G</P><P>H</P></BODY>"
    1 HEAD ""
     1 TITLE ""
    1 BODY "<P>G</P><P>H</P>"
     1 P "G"
      3 #text "G"
     1 P "H"
      3 #text "H"
-----------------
After changing second P's .innerTEXT to "pipapo"
 oDOM.documentElement: HTML
 oDOM.childNodes.length 1
   1 HTML "<HEAD></HEAD><BODY><P>G</P><P>pipapo</P></BODY>"
    1 HEAD ""
     1 TITLE ""
    1 BODY "<P>G</P><P>pipapo</P>"
     1 P "G"
      3 #text "G"
     1 P "pipapo"
      3 #text "pipapo"
-----------------
After deleting first P
 oDOM.documentElement: HTML
 oDOM.childNodes.length 1
   1 HTML "<HEAD></HEAD><BODY><P>pipapo</P></BODY>"
    1 HEAD ""
     1 TITLE ""
    1 BODY "<P>pipapo</P>"
     1 P "pipapo"
      3 #text "pipapo"
-----------------
After using DOM to append an H1
 oDOM.documentElement: HTML
 oDOM.childNodes.length 1
   1 HTML "<HEAD></HEAD><BODY><P>pipapo</P><H1>tritratrulala</H1></BODY>"
    1 HEAD ""
     1 TITLE ""
    1 BODY "<P>pipapo</P><H1>tritratrulala</H1>"
     1 P "pipapo"
      3 #text "pipapo"
     1 H1 "tritratrulala"
      3 #text "tritratrulala"
-----------------
After overwriting first P's outerHTML "<span>abracadabra</span>"
 oDOM.documentElement: HTML
 oDOM.childNodes.length 1
   1 HTML "<HEAD></HEAD><BODY><SPAN>abracadabra</SPAN><H1>tritratrulala</H1></BODY>"
    1 HEAD ""
     1 TITLE ""
    1 BODY "<SPAN>abracadabra</SPAN><H1>tritratrulala</H1>"
     1 SPAN "abracadabra"
      3 #text "abracadabra"
     1 H1 "tritratrulala"
      3 #text "tritratrulala"
-----------------
```

(qq(), nodeType constants, and a strategy to avoid those

```
oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).removeChild oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).childNodes(0)
```

nastities are left as exercise)

Comment: OK, thanks for your lengthy answer. I thought that there is maybe general method for resetting object data. Removing root node is fine approach. Cheers

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner
Sorry to stress you but seems vbscript is a dead language and nobody is answering:
I have a vbscript question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086814/classic-asp-htmlfile-object-remove-child)
if you could be so kind to read it and suggest a solution would be a great help for me. Thanks. Joe