# classic asp htmlfile object remove child

Tags: html, dom, asp-classic, removechild

have to extract some info from an HTML File and strip out a div and I need to use classic asp.

I'm using HTMLFile object and it works everything except when I try to remove the div

here the relevant part of the routine:

```
.......

Set HTML = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
Set Frame = CreateObject("HTMLFile")  

.........  

tmp=t.ReadAll
HTML.Write tmp
t.close

Set SPN=HTML.getElementsByTagName("div")
for each sp in SPN
    if sp.getAttribute("id")="frame" then
        Frame.write sp.InnerHTML
        exit for
    end if
next        

Set Divs=Frame.getElementsByTagName("div")
for each div in Divs
    if div.getAttribute("id")="link_1" then
        Frame.removeChild(div)
    end if
next
```

it returns

> htmlfile error '80070057'
>   Invalid argument
>   Line 57

Where command is `Frame.Removechild(div)`

can suggest solution or a link where can find documentation about HTMLFile Object.. since I googled a lot but apparently with wrong keywords

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** that the Docs for HTMLFILE start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

According to the docs for [removeChild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the incantation needed to remove node X is:

```
X.parentNode.removeChild X
```

If you change the delete demo code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11952094/603855)

```
oDOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).removeChild DOM.childNodes(0).childNodes(1).childNodes(0)
```

to

```
  Set p = oDOM.getElementsByTagName("P")(0)
  p.parentNode.removeChild p
  WScript.Echo "After deleting first P"
  dumpDoc oDOM
```

you should get

...

```
-----------------
After changing second P's .innerTEXT to "pipapo"
 oDOM.documentElement: HTML
 oDOM.childNodes.length 1
   1 HTML "<HEAD></HEAD><BODY><P>G</P><P>pipapo</P></BODY>"
    1 HEAD ""
     1 TITLE ""
    1 BODY "<P>G</P><P>pipapo</P>"
     1 P "G"
      3 #text "G"
     1 P "pipapo"
      3 #text "pipapo"
-----------------
After deleting first P
 oDOM.documentElement: HTML
 oDOM.childNodes.length 1
   1 HTML "<HEAD></HEAD><BODY><P>pipapo</P></BODY>"
    1 HEAD ""
     1 TITLE ""
    1 BODY "<P>pipapo</P>"
     1 P "pipapo"
      3 #text "pipapo"
-----------------
...
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for prompt answer.. I understood where I was wrong, although, knowing the ID of the div the easiest way to remove it was to use `removeNode` Method.. but I discovered just now after reading at the link you passed me.
Thanks again!